# How to stop get returned email from email address that never sent

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces

I am receiving tons of returned emails that I had never sent before. Is there any way to stop it? It seems that my email auto sent to some email address that block my email address.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(e-mail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you receive bounces as a reaction to spam mails, that a spammer is sending with your email address as `From:` address.

For more informations see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(e-mail) (as commented by ceejayoz ).

As a workaround you may:

- use a filter rule in your Mail User Agent (e.g. Thunderbird)
- use a sieve filter rule, if your Mail Delivery Agent (e.g. Dovecot) support this
- use procmail to filter out this messages

Comment: Thank you so much.If I sent an email to abc@xyz.com and it failed, so I get returned  email like that :[From]Mail Delivery System.....................This message was created automatically by mail delivery software..........How can I stop it in Cpanel. Thanks (I mean turn it off whenever my email sending unsuccessful)